# typedef in C++ to summarize and define a new type with two functions

Tags: c++, function, typedef

I have two function that returns a boolean value after comparing the two values that I am passing to the function. Now by question is how can we write a typedef using the following two functions to characterize them and define a new type?

```
 functions: 
    bool compare1(float n1, float n2){
      return n1<n2;
    }

    bool compare2(int n1, int n2){
      return n1<n2;
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with such typedef?

Comment: don't really understand what you're asking, but `typedef` doesn't define a new type, it creates an alias

Comment: It sounds like you may want to look into some sort of [polymorphism](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/polymorphism/intro/), [overloading](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm) in particular, instead of typedefs.

Comment: A typedef would make sense if you used only **one** type throughout your code and you needed to change it from time to time.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a typedef doing much good here, but a template certainly could:

```
template <class T>
bool compare(T n1, T n2) { 
   return n1 < n2;
}
```

Note that this is pretty much the same as `std::less<T>` already provides, except that `std::less<T>` has specializations so it works with some types for which `n1<n2` wouldn't necessarily give meaningful results. That means this exact case isn't very practical, but other cases of the general idea can be.

For the original case, you can't really use a `typedef`. You can create a `typedef` for the type of a pointer to one of the functions:

```
typedef bool (*ptr_func)(int, int);
```

But that still needs the parameter types specified, so you can't use it to refer to both functions that takes `int` parameters and functions that take `float` parameters. You can create a `typedef` for a pointer to a function that takes a variadic argument list, but even though such a function could take either `int` or `float` parameters, that pointer wouldn't be the right type to refer to either of the functions you've given.

Comment: The `using` syntax in the [answer by Piotr S.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25826918/509868) comes very close to `typedef`; some people actually call it a `typedef`, even though it has another keyword in it.

Comment: @anatolyg: Yes, since C++11, `using` can give a roughly similar result to a `typedef`. It's not at all clear that it accomplishes anything even vaguely similar to what the OP really wants though. It might, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

If you **really really** want to have *an alias* (aka *typedef*), then here it is:

```
bool compare1(float n1, float n2){
  return n1<n2;
}

bool compare2(int n1, int n2){
  return n1<n2;
}

template <typename T>
using Alias = bool(*)(T,T);

int main()
{    
    Alias<float> a = compare1;
    std::cout << a(3.14f, 5.12f) << std::endl;

    Alias<int> b = compare2;
    std::cout << b(1, 2) << std::endl;
}
```

[<kbd>**LIVE DEMO**</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/959c018d575aedfa)

Comment: Good example (however contrived it might be) of the use of templates and [C++11] [using-declaration].

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want to do something like this:

```
template<typename T>
bool compare(T n1, T n2){
  return n1 < n2;
}
```